# Servers Redundancy/Fail over in different locations

Tags: windows, failover

One in a different city. These are individual servers, pretty much works as file servers. We upload images to those servers and at the end of the month we send the images to our clients (Digitalization services).

We have Darkfiber between sites so we can reach the LAN from any city. What I need to do is find a way to make HA/contigency/Fail over. It means  that if users in site C their server fails. They can use Site B or A to upload files. If site A server fails they can use Site B or C Server to upload files.

Keep in mind is not a cluster of servers but individual servers and everything is for internal use. Internet access is not required.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What file protocols do you want to use? Either way just use a distributed file system - which one will depend on the answer to my question but this sort of thing is very standard practice these days.